# How do you compute a homography given two poses?

Tags: python, opencv, homography

I have two camera matrices

```
P_1 = K_1 | [R_1|t_1]
P_2 = K_2 | [R_2|t_2]
```

HZ 13.2 says that you can compute a homography from two poses using this formula:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bp68pw2fm4nxwg8/Screenshot%202018-03-23%2020.18.09.png?dl=0

I have two questions:

1. Is `n^t/d` the normalized vector from the plane to one of the camera centers, is so how do I get a camera center for `P_1` or `P_2`
2. How do I get `R` and `t` from `P_1` and `P_2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For point 1, see this tutorial: [Demo 3: Homography from the camera displacement](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html#tutorial_homography_Demo3).

For point 2, you should be able to decompose `P` into `K` and `[R | t]`. See:

- [Dissecting the Camera Matrix, Part 1: Extrinsic/Intrinsic Decomposition](https://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/14/decompose/)
- [`decomposeProjectionMatrix()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gaaae5a7899faa1ffdf268cd9088940248)